# phone is in charging mode could not able to enable debugging mode

Tags: debugging

phone connected to computer is not detected by it. and the debugging mode in the developers options is completely greyed out though I enabled the top debugging option. Generating build number, rebooting  did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all possible options, finally figured it out.

Settings->storage->menu->USB Computer connection -> uncheck the Charge only button